# Only allow script access to a file iis7.5

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5, file-permissions

I have a file (called 'log.html') on my iis7.5 server that I would like my PHP installation to be able to access and write to, but I do not want anybody to access the file directly, for example typing in 'http://computername/log.html' (I am on a LAN).

How can I prevent users from accessing it but allow php to see it?

When using the web.config file suggested below, I get this error:
[image: web.config error]

Comment: Should I ask this on server fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I may have answered my own question! I still need to test it a bit more, and perhaps if it does not work completely then someone could correct me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="cache-control" value="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <denyUrlSequences>
                    <add sequence="log.html" />
                </denyUrlSequences>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The cache control bit prevents the browser from caching anything that it returned.

Hope this helps somebody else! I am still very new to this, so you might be able to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS URL Rewrite and create a *Request Blocking Rule* to prevent access over HTTP:

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="BlockLogFile" 
              patternSyntax="Wildcard" 
              stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="/log.html" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" 
                  statusCode="403" 
                  statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." 
                  statusDescription="This is sekret!" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: for some reason when I use your web.config example I get an internal server error (500.19) telling me that there was a problem reading the web.config file...

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - sorry, never noticed your reply. The config example was copied directly from the server I tested on. Can you post a screenshot of the 500.19 page, it's usually pretty informative.

Comment: Yes I can, but how can I display it on stackoverflow?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs the editor provides an image upload button. If you can't get that to work then can you upload to an external image hoster (imgur, imageshack or wherever), provide a link and I'll import it for you.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - I think you got that error because the IIS7 URL rewrite module wasn't/isn't installed.